# Splitting colum of a table into two columns while joining to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables:

**t1:**

```
Reference # Reference   TypeId
25253       1       60
30765       1       60
30765       3       61
33061       1       61
34037       6       60
35532       5       60
35750       1       60
35750       2       61
35750       4       61
35860       6       60
35860       2       61
35909       4       60
35936       5       60
35936       2       61
35965       1       61
36080       4       60
36080       2       61
36080       4       61
```

**t2:**

```
Id  TypeId  Reference   Description
360 60       1               Studio
361 60       2               1 bedroom
362 60       3               2 bedroom
363 60       4               3 bedroom
364 60       5               4 bedroom
365 60       6               5 bedroom
366 60       7               6 bedroom
367 61       1               Zone 1 - East
368 61       2               Zone 2 - South
369 61       3               Zone 3 - Central
370 61       4               Zone 4 - West
371 61       5               Zone 5 - North
```

I want to bring in **'Description'** column from t2 into t1 in such a way that description column split into two columns based on **TypeId** value. I wrote following query to join the tables:

```
Select t1.Reference#, t1.reference,t1.TypeId, 
Case when t1.TypeId = 60 then t2.description end as 'No of Bedrooms'
Case when t1.TypeId = 61 then t2.description end as 'Zone'
from t1 
join t2 on t1.TypeId = t2.TypeId and t1.reference = t2.reference
```

Above lines produced following output:

**Result:**

```
Reference#  Reference   TypeId  No of Bedrooms  Zone
25253          1           60   Studio           NULL
30765          1           60   Studio           NULL
30765          3           61   NULL             Zone 3 - Central
33061          1           61   NULL             Zone 1 - East
34037          6           60   5 bedroom        NULL
35532          5           60   4 bedroom        NULL
35750          1           60   Studio           NULL
35750          2           61   NULL             Zone 2 - South
35750          4           61   NULL             Zone 4 - West
35860          6           60   5 bedroom        NULL
35860          2           61   NULL             Zone 2 - South
35909          4           60   3 bedroom        NULL
35936          5           60   4 bedroom        NULL
35936          2           61   NULL             Zone 2 - South
35965          1           61   NULL             Zone 1 - East
36080          4           60   3 bedroom        NULL
36080          2           61   NULL             Zone 2 - South
36080          4           61   NULL             Zone 4 - West
```

The problem with above output is that it shows either value of 'No of Bedrooms' or 'Zone' in a row. It wont show both values in the same row. My desired output looks like as follow:

**Desired output:**

[image]

Not sure simple join would work for the desired output. Any help would be appreciated to get the desired output.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: While awaiting usable data, I have a couple of questions: (1) Do you need the Reference and TypeId columns in the result? (2) If you need Reference, would separate BedroomsReference and ZoneReference columns be acceptable substitutes? (3) Do you really need need multiple rows in the results if there are at most a single type 60 and single type 61 row in the input, like for 30765? (4) For 35750, would two rows be sufficient to show every combination of #Bedrooms and Zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
;With JoinedData as (
    Select t1.ReferenceNo, t2.TypeId, t2.Reference, t2.Description
    from t1
    join t2 on t2.TypeId = t1.TypeId and t2.Reference = t1.Reference
)
Select
    COALESCE(t60.ReferenceNo, t61.ReferenceNo) as ReferenceNo,
    t60.Reference as NoOfBedroomsReference,
    t61.Reference as ZoneReference,
    t60.Description as NoOfBedrooms,
    t61.Description as Zone
  
from (
    Select *
    from JoinedData
    where TypeId = 60
) t60
full outer join (
    Select *
    from JoinedData
    where TypeId = 61
) t61
    on t61.ReferenceNo = t60.ReferenceNo
order by ReferenceNo, t60.Reference, t61.Reference
```

The same without using a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
Select
    COALESCE(t60.ReferenceNo, t61.ReferenceNo) as ReferenceNo,
    t60.Reference as NoOfBedroomsReference,
    t61.Reference as ZoneReference,
    t60.Description as NoOfBedrooms,
    t61.Description as Zone
from (
    Select t1.ReferenceNo, t2.TypeId, t2.Reference, t2.Description
    from t1
    join t2 on t2.TypeId = t1.TypeId and t2.Reference = t1.Reference
    where t1.TypeId = 60
) t60
full outer join (
    Select t1.ReferenceNo, t2.TypeId, t2.Reference, t2.Description
    from t1
    join t2 on t2.TypeId = t1.TypeId and t2.Reference = t1.Reference
    where t1.TypeId = 61
) t61
    on t61.ReferenceNo = t60.ReferenceNo
order by ReferenceNo, t60.Reference, t61.Reference
```

For each ReferenceNo, this takes every number-of-bedrooms attribute value and cross joins it to every Zone attribute value.

Results:

| ReferenceNo | NoOfBedroomsReference | ZoneReference | NoOfBedrooms | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25253 | 1 | null | Studio | null |
| 30765 | 1 | 3 | Studio | Zone 3 - Central |
| 33061 | null | 1 | null | Zone 1 - East |
| 34037 | 6 | null | 5 bedroom | null |
| 35532 | 5 | null | 4 bedroom | null |
| 35750 | 1 | 2 | Studio | Zone 2 - South |
| 35750 | 1 | 4 | Studio | Zone 4 - West |
| 35860 | 6 | 2 | 5 bedroom | Zone 2 - South |
| 35909 | 4 | null | 3 bedroom | null |
| 35936 | 5 | 2 | 4 bedroom | Zone 2 - South |
| 35965 | null | 1 | null | Zone 1 - East |
| 36080 | 4 | 2 | 3 bedroom | Zone 2 - South |
| 36080 | 4 | 4 | 3 bedroom | Zone 4 - West |

Only the 35750 and 36080 ReferenceNo values are repeated, because they have multiple values for the same attribute.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dRqycvBJ) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

You could use window functions with your query as the following:

```
SELECT t1.Reference#, 
       t1.reference,
       t1.TypeId, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.TypeId = 60 THEN t2.description END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Reference#) AS [No of Bedrooms],
       CASE
        WHEN t1.TypeId = 60 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.TypeId = 61 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Reference#) = 1
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN t1.TypeId = 61 THEN t2.description END) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Reference#)
        WHEN t1.TypeId = 61 
         THEN t2.description
       END AS [Zone]
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
  ON t1.TypeId = t2.TypeId AND t1.reference = t2.reference
ORDER BY t1.Reference#, t1.TypeId, t1.reference
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0b35MI83)